# I am trying to get items from xampp using php and ionic 3 using a select statement and i am having an issue where it is returning a null value

Tags: php, ionic-framework, xampp

this is my ionic 3 code where i am sending the DoctorName to php and in the console.log(this.items) it is returning null values.

```js
constructor(public http: Http,public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  this.User=navParams.get('Username');
}

load() {
  this.http
      .get('http://localhost:10080/testdb/retrieve-data.php?Doctorname='+this.User)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.items = data;        
      });

  console.log(this.items);
}
```

And this is the php code , the connect.php is the connection to the xampp localhost:

```php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
include ("connect.php");

$Doctorname= $_GET['Doctorname'];
//$Doctorname='aa';

$arr = array();
$sql="SELECT Name FROM patentadd WHERE DoctorName = '$Doctorname'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $arr[]= $row;
}

echo json_encode($arr);
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: what you get  when open this url in browser.replace this user `http://localhost:10080/testdb/retrieve-data.php?Doctorname='+this.User` ?

Comment: when i am doing an insert to the database it is working fine but when i'm trying to display to ionic it is giving some errors , the $Doctorname= $_GET['Doctorname']; is working fine

Comment: http://localhost:10080/testdb/retrieve-data.php?Doctorname=ss is giving : [{"Name":"name"}] , the value in the xampp